# Visual C++ - Автоматизация IE

Tags: веб-программирование, html, internet-explorer, c++

Всем привет! У меня встала тема с автоматизацией IE. Нужно написать программу которая будет скрытно открывать IE, изменять значения input, читать их, оправлять формы, нажимать по тегам. Очень много искал на эту тему в гугле пришел к ihtmldocument2 в справке майкрософта. Но примера кода который можно вставить в visual studio и начать разбираться я не нашел. Может кто то таким занимался или кто может помочь примерами то прошу отозваться. Всем заранее спасибо!

справка по ihtmldoc2
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(v=vs.85).aspx#properties